# How to refresh business view in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, business-objects

I have developed a business view and used it in report. Till now there is no issue, but when I change the business element in business view, it is not getting updated in the report and every time I change I am forced to create a new report which is a very tedious task as the report is very complex and has approx 80 columns.

I have tried different ways to update the business view, `Set Datasource Location`, `Verify database` and creating a new connection and updating the old one with new one, but nothing was working for me.

I guess there would be some way to update the business view without creating new report every time.

How can I achieve this task so that without creating new report all changes will get updated in the original report that are in changed business view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to found the solution from other forums... posting here so that others can use.

Restarted the Crystal reports after changing the `Business Element` and `Data Foundation` and after restarting the Crystal reports used the option `Verify Database` then I was able to see the changes in my report.